# How to compare if class have many filed value?

Tags: java

I want to compare A object to B object of Fruit class. 
 I want to get true if value of filed of A object is the same value of filed of B object
I am knowing that A == B compares adress. Threfore i Need to override equals for compare.
But my class has many field.

I make code to compare

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Fruit {
    //if I have 100 Filed
    int filed1;

    int filed2;

    int filed3;

    int filed4;

    ....


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Fruit) {
            Fruit target = (Fruit)obj;
            // I want to compare this object with targetFooResponse
            if(this.getFiled1() != target.getFiled1()) {
                return false;
            }
            if(this.getFiled2() != target.getFiled2()) {
                return false;
            }
            //I need to add if condition of 98 in the future

            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think my code is very inefficiently.I want to reduce if conditions
Is there a good way to compare?

Comment: You're code is ugly because having a class with 100 fields is a terrible idea. But if that's what you've got, then this is not the worst way to compare them. Also, it's "field" not "filed".

Comment: the one optimization I might make is chaining the conditions with a `&&` operator: `this.getFiled1() == target.getFiled1 && this.getFiled2 == target.getFIled2() ...`

Comment: Totally agree with Joachim Sauer, That's why we have concept of array ... If you haven't exposed yourself to array search for it...

Comment: `Arrays.stream(getClass().getFields()).map(f->{if(!f.getName().startsWith("filed")) return true;f.setAccessible(true);try {return f.get(this).equals(f.get(obj));} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}return false;}).allMatch(e -> e)` will return whether all the `filedN` fields are equal on the two objects, but it's a dirty way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's a bad idea to have a class with 100 fields. It violates many good SW engineering principles.

Still, let's say you have a class with many fields ( maybe it's auto generated? )

Here's a cute idea. If you can make your class serializable , and all the fields to examine are serializable, you can dump each object to a byte array stream and compare the streams.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

class A implements Serializable {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        A a1 = new A();     a1.a = 1;       a1.b = 2;       a1.c = 3;
        A a2 = new A();     a2.a = 1;       a2.b = 2;       a2.c = 3;
        byte[] bytes1 = getBytes(a1);
        byte[] bytes2 = getBytes(a2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(bytes1,bytes2));
    }


    private static byte[] getBytes(A a) throws IOException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);) {            

            out.writeObject(a);
            out.flush();
            return bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not feel comfortable invoking serialization in an `equals()` implementation. I haven't tried it but wouldn't be surprised if serializing and object involved an  `equals()` call at some point which could lead to an endless recursion.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well they don't in my example ( overriding for class A) , but who knows, maybe in some scenarios.

Comment: That is cute idea.Thank you